# Qt Passing variables between unrelated objects

Tags: c++, qt, class, variables, object

I am currently learning Qt and I seem to have run into a problem. 
In my practice project I have 2 classes: MainWindow and Dialog.

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "dialog.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButtonDialog_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog *dialogInstance;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    dialogInstance = new Dialog(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonDialog_clicked()
{
    dialogInstance->show();
}
```

**Dialog.h**

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

**Dialog.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

My goal is to input a value using the Dialog window, then have the value of that input shown on the MainWindow, I know how to pass variables around within the class using widgets, but I am not sure how to transfer variables between unrelated objects.

Any input would be of great help.

Comment: You can connect `signals` from widgets in one class to `slots` in other objects/widgets of other objects... what is the problem you're actually having?

Comment: Does the Dialog class have to have it's own MainWindow object in order to be able to use signals and slots?

Comment: No. `connect` a signal from the dialog to a `slot` in the `MainWindow`.

Comment: @user1502207 You forgot to connect SIGNAL(clicked) from your pushButton to corresponding slot (`on_pushButtonDialog_clicked`). So the slot is never called. Avoid using form designer to add functionality to your GUI.

Comment: @sorush-r Hey, thanks for replying, my problem is that Dialog doesn't have a MainWindow object.

Comment: @sorush-r Thank you for the code example it helped cement the concept in my mind, now I understand why you don't use form designer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButtonDialog, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButtonDialog_clicked()));
    dialogInstance = new Dialog(this);
}
// ...
```

Comment: This was not his question. His question was how to parse veriables between the Dialog and the MainWindow.

Comment: In your example you are not parsing variables at all, you only connect a signal to a slot. The answer would be that a variable can simply be parsed by using f.e. (last line) `QDialog* about = new QDialog(0,0); settingsUi.setupUi(about); settingsUi.spinBoxMin->setValue(absMin);`